# Trim curly braces from string

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am using a Prolog query in a Common Lisp program to get the date of birth from a knowledge base. The query returns the value formatted as `{1991-05-13}`, and I assign to this value on `dob` variable with `setq`: `(setq dob {1991-05-13})`. I want to use this date value in a new function which takes string, so I am trying to use `write-to-string` to convert `dob` to a string with   `(setq strdob (write-to-string dob))`,  but it returns

```
"{1991-05-13}"
```

I actually want:

```
"1991-05-13"
```

which lacks the curly braces.  How could I trim the curly braces from the string?

Answer (score 4):

```
CL-USER 13 > (string-trim '(#\{ #\}) "{1991-05-13}")
"1991-05-13"

CL-USER 14 > (string-trim "{}" "{1991-05-13}")
"1991-05-13"
```

Comment: Alternatively, `(string-trim "{}" "{1991-05-13}")` (the character-bag can be any sequence and it may be more natural to express it as a string).

Comment: @Vatine: that's a very useful remark. Thanks! I've added it as example.